# How can I access application context of helper file in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have main activity and onClick method I am executing JsonTask

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.blogin:
              new JsonTask().execute("https://www.aboutmyclinic.com/android/index.php","login" );
            break;
}
```

I have created a helper file called JsonTask to pass th post parameters to server and to get the json response from server

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {...
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    JSONObject json = null;
    String sucessvalue = null;
    String errorvalue = null;
    String token = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(result);
        sucessvalue = json.getString("Success");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (sucessvalue != null) {
        new Preferences().PutExtra("Success",sucessvalue);
    } else {
        // Content.setText(result);
    }

}
}
```

I have another helper file called Preferences to get and set sharedPreferences. Here is the code

```
public class Preferences  extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

public Preferences(){

    sharedpreferences =getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void PutExtra(String key, String value)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}
public String getExtra(String key, String defaultValue)
{

    return sharedpreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
}
```

I am getting error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

I am not able to get a context from main activity in Preferences helper file.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Pass Context in `Preferences ` class constructor to access `getSharedPreferences` method

Comment: getApplicationContext() ? or else you will have to pass the context to your Preferences class

Comment: it clearly showing on error you have to add Context in Preferences

Comment: I m using new preferences.putExtra() in jsonTask helper file. How can i pass context from one helper file to another .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code

Your Preference Helper class should not extend Appcompat activity

```
  public class PreferencesHelper {

        private static PreferencesHelper preferenceHelperInstance;

        private PreferencesHelper() {
        }

        public static PreferencesHelper getPrefernceHelperInstace() {

            if (null == preferenceHelperInstance) {
                preferenceHelperInstance = new PreferencesHelper();
            }

            return preferenceHelperInstance;
        }

        public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";

        public void PutExtra(Context context, String key, String value) {

            context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(key, value).commit();

        }

        public String getExtra(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {

            return context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(key, defaultValue);
        }
    }
```

Pass context into your JSON executor with the help of Constructor

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private Context mContext;

    //Pass Context
    public JsonTask(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        JSONObject json = null;
        String sucessvalue = null;
        String errorvalue = null;
        String token = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
            sucessvalue = json.getString("Success");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (sucessvalue != null) {

            //Get Preferences
            PreferencesHelper.getPrefernceHelperInstace().PutExtra(mContext, "Success", sucessvalue);
        } else {
            // Content.setText(result);
        }

    }
}
```

Finally inject context for both Async task and PreferenceHelper like this

> new
>   JsonTask(getApplicationContext()).execute("https://www.aboutmyclinic.com/android/index.php",
>   "login");

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass **Context** to **Preferences Class**

First change constructer

```
public Preferences(Context context){
  sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

then call function like this

```
new Preferences(context).PutExtra("Success",sucessvalue);
```

Where

```
context = CurrentActivity.this;
```